# Tratar callback json do ERP Bling no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, callback, erp

Estou tendo dificuldades para tratar o seguinte retorno json do ERP Bling no Laravel:

```
array (
  'data' => '{"retorno":{"pedidos":[{"pedido":{"desconto":"0","observacoes":"","observacaointerna":"","data":"2018-10-20","numero":"6462","vendedor":"Mauricio Liell","valorfrete":"0.00","totalprodutos":"31.00","totalvenda":"31.00","situacao":"Atendido","cliente":{"nome":"Mauricio","cnpj":"xxx.xxx.xxx-xx","ie":"","rg":"","endereco":"Av. Dxxxxxx e","numero":"xxx","complemento":"","cidade":"Bom Principio","bairro":"Centro","cep":"95.765-000","uf":"RS","email":"xxxxxxxxx","celular":"","fone":"(51) xxxxxxxx},"itens":[{"item":{"codigo":"1","descricao":"Cimento Todas as Obras Votoran 50 KG","quantidade":"1.0000","valorunidade":"31.0000000000","precocusto":"23.5600000000","descontoItem":"0.00","un":"Sc"}}],"pagamento":{"categoria":"Venda de Mercadorias"},"parcelas":[{"parcela":{"valor":"31.00","dataVencimento":"2018-10-20 00:00:00","obs":"","forma_pagamento":{"id":455687,"descricao":"Ficha Financeira","codigoFiscal":99}}}]}}]}}',
)
```

O que preciso: salvar os seguintes dados do pedido: numero, data, totalvenda, vendedor, situacao, nome do cliente.

Tenho o seguinte código no controller:

```
$json_string = $request->all();

$json_string = $json_string['data'];


        //Log::critical($json_string);


        foreach ($json_string['retorno']['pedidos'] as $data ) {


            $pedido = IndicadoresPedido::firstOrNew(array('numero_pedido' => $data['pedido']['numero']));


            $pedido->numero_pedido = $data['pedido']['numero'];
            $pedido->data =  $data['pedido']['data'];
            $pedido->valor_total = $data['pedido']['totalvenda'];
            $pedido->vendedor =  $data['pedido']['vendedor'];
            $pedido->situacao =  $data['pedido']['situacao'];
            $pedido->cliente =  $data['pedido']['cliente']['nome'];

            if ($pedido->save()){

                $sucesso[] = $pedido;
            };

        }
```

E estou recebendo o erro:

```
production.ERROR: Illegal string offset 'retorno' {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Illegal string offset 'retorno' at /var/www/interno/app/Http/Controllers/apiController.php:33)
```

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão, agradeço muito.

Comment: O erro diz que o índice 'retorno' não existe em $json_string. De um var_dump em $json_string para ver o que tem dentro da variável. Se tiver uma string você tem que fazer o parse dela com json_decode. Se tiver um objeto do tipo StdClass, você tem que acessar os atributos com a sintaxe $json_string->retorno->pedidos.

Comment: Certo, desde já muito obrigado pela ajuda. Atualizei as informações acima. Na verdade está retornando um array com as informações dentro de 'data'. Inseri o ['data'] e retorna o erro mencionado. Como posso acertar isso?

Comment: Acho que foi o que o amigo acima falou. Dê um json_decode($json_string). Deve funcionar.

Comment: Consegui resolver a partir das sugestões acima. Muito obrigado!